# Copy a billion records from one table to another

Tags: oracle-12c

I have Oracle database 12 with tablespace with bigfile Yes

I have limited to 120Gb file data so I need change my tablespace to bigfile no and create multi datafile for my tablespace.

I need to export or copy data from old to new table but my problem is I have over 1 billion records and I don't know what is the fastest way to copy this table to another table.

```
CREATE TABLE C##USER.READ 
(
  DEVICEID NUMBER(38, 0) 
, THETIME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, THEH VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) 
, ENERGYEXPORT NUMBER(10, 0) 
, LOADPROFILE NUMBER(10, 0) 
, DEMANDREGISTER NUMBER(10, 0) 
, AREA NUMBER(38, 0) 
, STATUSM NUMBER(2, 0) 
) 
TABLESPACE TABLE_SPACE 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL 
PARTITION BY LIST (AREA) 
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (THETIME) 
(
  PARTITION AREAPART VALUES (DEFAULT) 
  TABLESPACE TABLE_SPACE 
  PCTFREE 10 
  INITRANS 1 
  STORAGE 
  ( 
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
  ) 
  NOCOMPRESS NO INMEMORY 
  (
    SUBPARTITION AREAPART_THETIME VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) 
    NOCOMPRESS NO INMEMORY  
  )  
);

CREATE INDEX C##USER.READ_INDEX1 ON C##USER.READ (DEVICEID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE TABLE_SPACE 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;
```

The tablespace Sql :

```
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE TABLE_SPACE 
    DATAFILE 
        '~\TABLE_SPACE.DBF' SIZE 127301910528 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 8192 MAXSIZE 35184372064256 
    BLOCKSIZE 8192 
    DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS NO INMEMORY 
    ONLINE 
    SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO 
    EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the original table from the old tablespace to the new tablespace instead. There is no need to create a new table and copy the records.

For a partitioned object, move each partition individually. See:

- [Online Move of Partitions and Sub-Partitions in Oracle 12c Release 1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-move-partitions-and-subpartitions-12cr1) by Tim Hall.
- [About Moving Partitions and Subpartitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-3DB0B6A6-FD33-4355-8BAC-7C5B4BE4C4E0.htm#VLDBG1193) in the Oracle Database VLDB and Partitioning Guide.